# PDO Prepared statement returns nothing even tho MySQL Statement does

Tags: php, database, class, pdo

i have been doing some php development for a project in class and i have encountered a problem.

The following function is supposed to return true when used with parameters i have entered myself, but it returns false :

```
public function check_if_in($table, $condition){
    $request="SELECT *"; // Selecting one column
    $request=$request.' FROM '.$table.' WHERE '; // From the table i want to check in
        $keys = array_keys($condition);
        foreach($condition as $clé=>$val){
            if(!($clé == end($keys))){ // If it's not the last condition
                    $request = $request.$clé." = :".$clé." AND "; // add AND
            }
            else{
                $request = $request.$clé." = :".$clé.";"; // Add a semicolon
            }
        }
        try {
            $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($request); // Prepare the statement
        }
        catch (PDOException $e){
            die("Erreur array :" . $e->getMessage());
        }
        foreach($condition as $clé=>$val) {
            $statement->bindValue($clé, '%'.$val.'%'); // Binding all the parameters
        }

    try {
        $statement->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
            die("Error :" . $e->getMessage());
    }
    if($statement->rowCount() > 0){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Where would seem to be the problem please ?

Comment: You are using prepared statements incorrectly, the point is to not concatenate _any_ strings, which includes your table name (Unless it's verified another way, because your current code is vulnerable to SQL Injection).

Comment: Hello, the table name is not entered by the user at any moment, i'm defining it myself.

Edit : This function is to be used in multiple php pages, it's my teacher's orders

Comment: Try echoing out your query just to verify that it looks correct, then submit it directly to your database with the quoted values. If you have access to the database server, you can turn on MySQL logging (`SET GLOBAL general_log = 1;`) before you run your script, turn it off afterwards, and check the mysql log to find the exact query that it's passing.

Comment: Hi, would've done that but as i'm at the university, i can't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be a combination of the query and the variables you bind:

The query is built like this:

```
// You use `=` to compare values
$request = $request.$clé." = :".$clé
```

And you bind your variables like this:

```
// You use `%` characters as if it is a `LIKE`
$statement->bindValue($clé, '%'.$val.'%');
                             ^        ^ here you have a problem
```

You are using `%` signs like you would be using wildcards in a `LIKE` condition, but you are using `=`.

Now your query is looking for literal strings that are surrounded by `%` signs. Which (probably...) don't exist.

So either use `LIKE` instead of `=` or get rid of the `%` characters where you bind the variables:

```
$statement->bindValue($clé, $val);
```

Comment: Or, get rid of all of the loops in the function and replace it with `$statement->execute($condition);`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton True, there is still room for improvements :-)

Comment: Hi, this still returned an empty array, let me try the $statement->execute($condition) thing.

Comment: Still an empty array, here's the $statement->debugDumpParams() if you need it : 

SQL: [74] SELECT * FROM Utilisateur WHERE username = :username AND passwd = :passwd; Params: 2 Key: Name: [9] :username paramno=-1 name=[9] ":username" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [7] :passwd paramno=-1 name=[7] ":passwd" is_param=1 param_type=2

Comment: @Baka So what are the values of the parameters and do you actually have rows with these combinations? Note that if your passwords are correctly hashed, you should not be able to find any rows this way at all.

Comment: @jeroen Here is the condition array : $cond = ['username' => '"'.$_POST['usrnm'].'"', 'passwd' => $pass];
My $table is 'Utilisateur'.
$pass is the hashed $_POST of the password field

Comment: Alright, problem found.

I put double quotes to each of my statements and later on i might've re-added them (so it would check for ""myusername"" instead of "myusername"). Thank you for helping and have a great day !